# Classifying changes in Dirichlet distribution over time?

Tags: classification, dirichlet-distribution

I'm interested in studying user preferences regarding streaming content. Given a discrete number of categories (ex: adventure, horror, comedy, family, drama) and the amount of time a given user watches content of each genre, the per user per month per genre percentages could be determined

```
user, month, genre, percent
----,------,------,--------
1,   1,     1,     50%
1,   1,     2,     30%
1,   1,     3,     10%
1,   1,     4,     5%
1,   1,     5,     5%
...
```

Over time, a given user's genre viewership might fluctuate month over month. There are two interesting cases, and I want to identify a means to distinguish them.

1. **Noise**, suppose in the above example, user 1 in month 7, viewership of genre 4 (family) swells to 20%, but in the months that follow it returns to the typical baseline.
2. **Change**, suppose that starting in month 7, percent viewership of genre 4 not only swells to 20% but hovers around this region for the remainder of the observed data. In effect, the user's preferences have changed.

I believe that the Dirichlet distribution can model proportional viewership per user per genre. However, I'm interested in classifying whether a change therein is case 1 (short term noise) or case 2 (change in preference).

My questions are:

1. How might this be done?
2. Is what I'm describing an established problem/research area? If so, where can I read more?

Comment: You described us an intended solution, but could you go one step back and describe in greater detail the problem you are trying to solve? Dirichlet distribution doesn't necessarily need to have anything in common with it.

Comment: @Tim Sure! Taking a step, the goal is to determine whether change in viewership month over months is simply noise or if the user's preferences have actually changed.

Comment: Without using Dirichlet distribution, simply comparing entropy (of percent genre viewership) across months might be a helpful building block

Comment: So your aim is to do some kind of anomaly detection for each user and category over time?

Comment: I think that's fair; anomaly else structural change. Where identifying structural change would be highly valuable

Comment: Can't you simply run univariate anomaly or changepoint detection per each user-genre pair? It may be way simpler to do.

Comment: I'm curious how a decision would be made on the joint distribution over genres if each genre is treated independently? They sum to 1 when normalized, so I suppose that a legitimate change in *any* would imply a change in the joint.

Comment: @Tim, after reviewing change point detection literature, I do not believe that this methodology would detect a true change in trend as distinct from an outlier/anomaly; could you clarify?